# Java - Android Studio - .xml file doesn't exist error

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using Android Studio. I am currently trying to make a custom adapter and I have been having trouble with my .xml files. Although I have created them and added the content I would like to see in them, when I call for them in the main activity Java file, I get an error saying it does not exist. Additionally, the SetOnItemClickListener and setAdapter will not work. None of my other files show any sort of errors.

.xml I would like to show, titled characteritem_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail_status"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail_explanation"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code for the main activity:

```
package com.example.app.activities;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button denButton;
    private Button sweButton;
    private Button aboutButton;
    private TextView welcome;
    private ArrayList<CharacterItem> characters;
    private ListView charList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.characteritem_layout)

        welcome = findViewById(R.id.welcome_screen);

       //The other buttons work perfectly well.

        initializeList();

        final CharacterAdapter charAdapter = new CharacterAdapter(this, R.layout.characteritem_layout, characters);
        characters.setAdapter(charAdapter);

        characters.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CharacterActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("charItem", characters.get(position));


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

   private void initializeList(){
        characters = new ArrayList<CharacterItem>();
        characters.add(new CharacterItem("Finland", false, "Not in progress yet"));
        characters.add(new CharacterItem("Norway", true, "Getting the Viking trio in first!"));
        characters.add(new CharacterItem("Iceland",false,"He's next!"));
    }


    }
```

Comment: One most definitely cannot use `.setContentView()` twice.

Comment: For the non-existent XML, clean and rebuild your project (look in the Build menu), and if that doesn't work, do Invalidate Caches/Restart (in the File menu). There's apparently some issue with a recent version of Android Studio that glitches when a new layout is created. As far as the other issues, `setAdapter()` and `setOnItemClickListener()` should be called on your `ListView charList`, not the `ArrayList<CharacterItem> characters`. Probably just some typos in transcribing an example.

Comment: [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) is for ID & text; for more fields you might need to use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview).

Comment: Oh, it seems as though the first two comments helped me a lot! Thank you both. It's doing what I want now.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, to use setContentView twice will not be working in way you want

in my case, right click layout folder and then chose new Layout Resource file works